# Poisson kernel, $E^{(x, y)}\text{exp}\{i\theta X_t - \theta Y_t\} = e^{i\theta x - \theta y}$

Tags: pr.probability, real-analysis, probability-distributions, brownian-motion

Let $d = 2$, and consider the domain $D = \mathbb{H}$, the upper half-plane. Let $W_t = (X_t, Y_t)$. How do I see that for any $\theta \in \mathbb{R}$ and any $t \ge 0$, we have$$E^{(x, y)}\text{exp}\{i\theta X_t - \theta Y_t\} = e^{i\theta x - \theta y}?$$

Comment: What happens when you hit the boundary? Do you stop the Brownian motion?

Comment: This is a homework exercise, please do not respond

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ignoring first the issue of boundary conditions, we note that by adding and subtracting an artificial $\frac{\theta^2}{2}t$ term in the exponential,

$\mathbb{E}\bigl[e^{i \theta X_t - \theta Y_t} \bigr] = \mathbb{E}\bigl[e^{i \theta X_t  + \frac{\theta^2}{2} t} \bigr]\mathbb{E}\bigl[e^{- \theta Y_t - \frac{\theta^2}{2}t}\bigr] = e^{i \theta x}e^{- \theta y} $

as the two exponentials are Doleans-Dade exponentials. If we impose absorbing boundary conditions, the result stays the same as stopped martingales are martingales, too.